# React-navigation default background color

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-stack

Is there a way to define in `react-navigation` v3 background color for all routes?
Currently, it's possible to set `cardStyle` for some particular `StackNavigator` but it seems do not work for nested navigators. That means I need wright same style on all levels.

So it would be nice to have solution where I define style once and it used in all instances of `StackNavigator`.